# Optimal way to find hierarchyid of a leaf node given a string path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

Given the path 'Applications/Accounting/Dashboard', what is the hierarchyid of the leaf node named 'Dashboard'.  I came up with this solution but is it optimal?

I am using this table and data where all children of a parent node are uniquely named.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resources](
    [Node] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/', N'Resource Root')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/1/', N'Applications')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/1/1/', N'Accounting')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/1/1/1/', N'Dashboard')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/1/2/', N'Asset Management')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/1/2/1/', N'Dashboard')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/2/', N'Assets')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/2/1/', N'X100022')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Node], [Name]) VALUES (N'/2/2/', N'X100017')
GO
```

The Resources table contains a hierarchy represented by this path 'Applications/Accounting/Dashboard'.  The SP below gets the leaf node named 'Dashboard'.

**I would like to know if it can be done without a cursor.  Or is there a more performant way to do this?**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeafNode]
  @Path NVARCHAR(500)
AS
  DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)
  DECLARE @ParentNode HIERARCHYID = HIERARCHYID::GetRoot()
  DECLARE @Level INT

  DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM string_split(@Path,'/')

  OPEN db_cursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name, @Level

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @ParentNode = Node FROM dbo.Resources WHERE Node.GetAncestor(1) = @ParentNode AND Name = @Name 
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name, @Level
  END

  CLOSE db_cursor
  DEALLOCATE db_cursor

  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Resources WHERE Node = @ParentNode AND Node.GetLevel() = @Level)
    SELECT @ParentNode
```

```
exec GetLeafNode 'Applications/Accounting/Dashboard'
```

Returns 0x5AD6 which is correct.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you provided a [mre].

Comment: Updated OP to make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: DECLARE your cursor as 'LOCAL FAST_FORWARD'. sometimes a cursor is the best way to solve a problem.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used hierarchyId much before, but my first thought would be to try a cte. Profile both methods to determine whether or not its any more efficient than a cursor.  This could probably be improved, but here's a starter example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb2cf30d173da65317e37dc910643938

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.HieracrchyId
,A.HierarchyId.ToString()
FROM [dbo].[Resources] AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Resources] AS B
ON A.HierarchyId = B.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1)
WHERE B.HierarchyId IS NULL
```

There's some good (but verbose) instructions around using hierarchyid which includes descriptions of methods like GetAncestor() and GetChild() etc.

There's other methods of representing a heirarchy in sql that you could look into like closure tables which can be more performant under certain conditions if you're not worried about the extra space taken up by storing the edges of the graph. It also allows you to detect circular references which can be helpful